# How to disable job name in print notifications for other logged in users?

Tags: server, printing, users, mate, privacy

We have a terminal server where users log in via Thinlinc. They are provided with a mate session. When a user prints a document, a notification of the successful print job pops up for *every* user. The popup contains the name of the printed document, which is a problem and not compatible with our privacy guidelines.

When viewing the job list in the cups interface, the job names and users are displayed anonymous, as desired.

I don't want to disable all notifications, because they give useful feedback on the print job for the user.

The printer is installed locally via cups (v. 2.1.3).
The server is running Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 with Ubuntu Mate Desktop installed.

Any suggestions on how to make the notifications visible only for the respective user are very much appreciated.